# difference between (defalias 'A (symbol-function 'B)) and (defalias 'A 'B)

Tags: emacs, function, elisp, alias

I was reading subr.el and saw this code:

```
(defalias 'backward-delete-char 'delete-backward-char)
(defalias 'search-forward-regexp (symbol-function 're-search-forward))
```

Interestingly, the first line doesn't use symbol-function while the second line does. The only difference I know of these two ways of using defalias is that the help for backward-delete-char (the first one) displays that it is an alias for delete-backward-char while the help for search-forward-regexp doesn't.

Is there a case when the second way is better than the first way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The two `defalias` usages are slightly different.  The first links the function cell for `'backward-delete-char` to that of `'delete-backward-char`.  The second links the `'search-forward-regexp` to the function that is currently called by `'re-search-forward`.

The difference is that if you later change the definition of '`delete-backward-char`, `'backward-delete-char` will now have the new behavior.  Whereas in the second case, changing the function for `'re-search-forward` has no effect on the behavior of `'search-forward-regexp`.

Perhaps some ascii art can help:

```
+-------------------------+     +-----------------+
|#<subr re-search-forward>| <-- |re-search-forward|
+-------------------------+     +-----------------+
                        ^       +---------------------+
                        \------ |search-forward-regexp|
                                +---------------------+

+----------------------------+     +--------------------+     +--------------------+
|#<subr delete-backward-char>| <-- |delete-backward-char| <-- |backward-delete-char|
+----------------------------+     +--------------------+     +--------------------+
```

This [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Indirection.html#Function-Indirection) might help clear things up.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it really is not the same thing... Here is a little game I just played:

```
(defun a () (message "hello"))
a
(a)
"hello"
(defalias 'b (symbol-function 'a))
(lambda nil (message "hello"))
(defalias 'c 'a)
a
(b)
"hello"
(c)
"hello"
(defun a () (message "howdy"))
a
(a)
"howdy"
(b)
"hello"
(c)
"howdy" ' c changed meaning, b did not...
```

Comment: Because `b` was aliased to the function definition and `c` was aliased to the symbol